# google sheet script export chart as vector image (svg/eps)

Tags: svg, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, export

I need to make a lot of chart with google sheet and download them to make a publication.

Because I need a lot, I will take too much time to use the right-clic -> export as image solution.

I found some way to export images as image jpg with this kind of code :

```
  function Export() {
  var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();     
  var sheet = Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var spreadsheetId =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var spreadsheetFile =  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
  var folderID = spreadsheetFile.getParents().next().getId();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); 

  // take the first chart of the sheet
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var Nom = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();

  //save to image
  var theBlob = chart.getBlob().getAs("image/jpeg").setName(NomFerme); //save the image into a blob
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob); //save the image into the spreadsheet folder
  return true;
 }
```

But for my project, I need to export vectorial images like in .svg or .eps.

I'm sure there is a way to do so because it work with the right-clic -> export as image solution.

But how to do it within a google script ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this custom function:

```js
function exportToSvg() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts()[0];
  DriveApp.createFile(ss.getBlob().getAs('image/jpeg'));
};
```

It downloads your first chart as **jpeg** to your Drive root folder

---

> but how about these MIME types:

- **image/svg+xml** returns error

*Converting from `image/png` to `image/svg+xml` is not supported. (line 3, file "macros")*

- **application/pdf** returns error as well

*Converting from `image/png` to `application/pdf` is not supported. (line 3, file "macros")*

---

Then I checked the official documentation for [getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getascontenttype) method:

For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. **For images** in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid.

---

Unfortunately, these are bad news and it is not possible to do what you are trying to do with `Apps Script`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried this with the same result than you unfortunatly...

Comment: Is there an other way to export chart than the getAs() solution ? I didn't try google chart yet but I don't know if i can use it with data stored in a spreadsheet...

Comment: [getBytes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getBytes()) but its very low level and I suppose you need external tools to create SVG from bytes